# How to override the after(:each) not to clean the database when using database_cleaner gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to clean the database just before my rspec examples run.
The default is it cleans the db after the examples run. How to configure it to clean the db just before the example run so that I can poke around the Test db to see what records were presisted?

Answer (score 0):

Put this function in your spec_helper

```
def clear_test_database
  ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.each do |klass|
   klass.destroy_all
  end
end
```

You can call this code in before(:all)